# VirtualBox import appliance error - oracle R12

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtualBox 5.1.0 and I am going to import the `oracle R12 ova` into the virtualBox. However, there appear a error that terminate the importing.

Error massage:

[image]

> Callee RC: 
>   RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE 0x800706BA (0x800706BA)

How can I fix this error and install the R12?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Open Cmd And type this command:

> 1- cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
> 2- VBoxSVC /ReRegServer
> 3- regsvr32 VBoxC.dll

See This [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/454321/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-callee-rc-regdb-e-classnotreg) for more info.